# Query All Knowledge__kav records

Tags: apex, apexrest

I am stuck with weird situation. When I execute the following query

```
SELECT Id, ... FROM Knowledge__kav
```

**Nothing is returned (0 records result)**

But when I execute the following query

```
SELECT Id, ... FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE Id='One of the articles values'
```

I am able to get any field value this way.

What could be the problem that is preventing me from retrieving all the articles? Any help?

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, please **[edit]** your post to include it verbatim.

Comment: @AdrianLarson No I don't get an error. I only get a 0 records result.

Comment: For me it is working. Getting record with first soql.

Comment: It is weird, because it's working fine on one of the dev orgs, but on other this problem is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you always have to add a fitler when querying knowledge. You cannot only query for all without a filter.

This documentation link: [Salesforce Knowledge with SOQL and SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_development_soql_sosl_intro.htm) seems to confirm it.

> Always filter on a single value of PublishStatus unless the query filters on one or more primary key IDs...

further details in the documentation. I would recommend adding a PublishStatus filter to your query.

Answer (score 1):

Yazan,
I don’t  believe the Knowledge__kav object supports an unfiltered query.
If you look at this document in the guide: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_development_soql_sosl_intro.htm

it shows that you need to filter on the status at a minimum. And, I think you may need to filter on one language only.

Comment: Thanks @JimRae. Filtering over the language was the defining point here!